# Rails has_many through – how to specify key columns for join table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### tl;dr

I would like to use *url_id* for both columns of a join table. Rails insist on using the primary key from documents table instead.

---

I have self-referencing *Document* class with *url_id* attribute. A document can reference other documents. I would like the join table with *url_id* as the connecting value like this:

- Desired state:

  ```
  Documents:           Document relationships:

  ID | URL_ID |        REFERRING_ID | REFERENCED_ID |          
  ---|--------|        -------------|---------------|
  1  | 1234   |        1234         | 1266          |
  2  | 1266   |        1234         | 2345          |
  3  | 2345   |        1266         | 426           |
  4  | 426    |        444          | 750           |
  5  | 750    |
  7  | 444    |
  ```

But I cannot persuade rails to use *url_id* as *referring_id* key.

With such a schema I could use something like following snippet of SQL to get related documents.

```
SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents"
INNER JOIN "document_relationships"
ON "documents"."url_id" = "document_relationships"."referenced_id"
WHERE "document_relationships"."referring_id" = ?
```

The closest I could get after going through [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) is this:

- Actual state:

  ```
  REFERRING_ID | REFERENCED_ID |
  -------------|---------------|
  1            | 1266          |
  1            | 2345          |
  2            | 426           |
  7            | 750           |
  ```

Nb. Rails are using **document_id** instead of **url_id** for *referring_id* column.

- Document classes:

  ```
  class Document < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :document_relationships, foreign_key: :referring_id
      has_many :related, through: :document_relationships, source: :referenced
  end

  class DocumentRelationship < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :referring, class_name: "Document"
      belongs_to :referenced, class_name: "Document", primary_key: :url_id
  end
  ```

Comment: Is it like parent and child relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the primary_key on both ends of the *document_relationships* - *referring* association:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :document_relationships, foreign_key: :referring_id, primary_key: :url_id
  has_many :related, through: :document_relationships, source: :referenced
end

class DocumentRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :referring, class_name: "Document", primary_key: :url_id
  belongs_to :referenced, class_name: "Document", primary_key: :url_id
end

# In case the url_id is not unique do not forget to use sth like Array's #uniq :
# Document.first.related.to_a.uniq(&:url_id)
```

Comment: This is it! I’ve tried adding primary key to the first `belongs_to` relation, but it had not occurred to me that I need to put it in `has_many` part too.